# C# cross thread dialogue co-operation

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0

K I am looking at a primarily single thread windows forms application in 3.0. Recently my boss had a progress dialogue added on a separate thread so the user would see some activity when the main thread went away and did some heavy duty work and locked out the GUI.

The above works fine unless the user switches applications or minimizes as the progress form sits top most and will not disappear with the main application. This is not so bad if there are lots of little operations as the event structure of the main form catches up with its events when it gets time so minimized and active flags can be checked and thus the dialog thread can hide or show itself accordingly.

But if a long running sql operation kicks off then no events fire. I have tried intercepting the WndProc command but this also appears queued when a long running sql operation is executing. I have also tried picking up the processes, finding the current app and checking various memory values isiconic and the like inside the progress thread but until the sql operation finishes none of these get updated. Removing the topmost causes the dialog to disappear when another app activates but if the main app is then brought back it does not appear again.

So I need a way to find out if the other thread is minimized or no longer active that does not involve querying the actual thread as that locks until the sql operation finishes.

Now I know that this is not the best way to write this and it would be better to have all the heavy processing on separate threads leaving the GUI free but as this is a huge ancient legacy  app the time to re-write in that fashion will not be provided so I have to work with what I have got.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the long running operation is bound to the progress dialog? That's usually a bad idea and I wonder whether the progress can be showed at all.
However you should consider using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker) for your long running operations. So your GUI (the main form as well as the progress dialog stays alive).
This way you should be able to send the minimize event of the main form to the progress dialog which can react to it instantly.

Btw. the `BackgroundWorker` supports progress reports on its own.

Comment: The long running op is firing on the main thread (and what was formally the only thread) as the GUI locks in earlier versions when this occurred the Progress Dialog was brought in to provide something which showed the user something was going on and the app had not just crashed. Arse about face but thats how all this has occurred.